# Using java class HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, https

I have a small piece of code which basically impements a HTTP-Client,
i.e. it POSTS request and works with re RESPONSE. As long as HTTP is
concenerned everthing work well. For some reason I now have to support
HTTPS too. So here is briefly what I do in order to get a connection opened:

```
 URL url = new URL(serverAddress);
 HttpsURLConnection httpsConn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

This fails, stating:

```
sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to com.sun.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
```

I guess this is kinda trivial, but I just don't get what I'm doing wrong in this one...
Googled it, and the code just looks right - not?

any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: `com.sun.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection` Why are you casting to this private API?

Comment: the import was created by eclipse' auto resolve. my d'oh.

Answer (score 29):

Just keep it [`java.net.URLConnection`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) or cast it to [`java.net.HttpURLConnection`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) instead. Both offers methods to do the desired task as good.

---

A side remark unrelated to the technical problem: you should *never* explicitly import/use Sun Java SE implementation specific classes in your code. Those are undocumented classes and are subject to changes which may cause your code break when you upgrade the JVM. On the other hand, your code may also break when you run it at a different brand JVM.

---

**Update**: since you seem to accidentally have imported it, go to *Window > Preferences > Java > Appearance > Type Filters* and  *Add* `com.sun.*` and `sun.*` to the list. This way you won't ever import them accidentally:

[image]

Answer (score 19):

Your url's protocol should also be https and not http. Check your url.

Answer (score 13):

The above problem is only caused by two issues

1. Using wrong import
2. Using `http` in the string you create url from use instead `https`

Comment: using http instead of https : yup - that got me. Thanks for the answer !

Answer (score 7):

Instead of creating a URL object using standard constructor like

```
URL wsURL = new URL(url);
```

Use

```
java.net.URL wsURL = new URL(null, url,new sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler());
```

which would solve this problem

Answer (score 6):

Check your imports, you should be using

```
java.net.HttpURLConnection
```

or

```
javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
```

Answer (score 5):

Check value of your "serverAddress" variable. It should https and not http

Answer (score 4):

Hard to tell without seeing the whole file, but it looks like you're importing com.sun.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection when you really want javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.

Answer (score 4):

**Change:**

```
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
```

and

```
URL url = new URL(serverAddress);
HttpsURLConnection httpsConn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

**Change To:**

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
```

and

```
URL url = new URL(serverAddress);
HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Comment: Please add explanation why this will fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the protocol and port were not correct while invoking the httpsUrlConnection.

Port and protocol were defined as static class variables. And the step prior to the failed step, was invoking an httpUrlConnection. That method changed the port/protocol to 80/http, but didn't set it back to /https at the end. So eventhough httpsUrlConnection was invoked, it was still using http/80. Once I reset those at the end of the httpUrlConnection method, the error disappeared.