# java.lang.ClassCastException: libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, android, http, https, urlconnection

I'm writing a bit of code to upload a file from the device to the cloud over HTTPS.

Relevant snippet:

```
HttpsURLConnection conn = null; 
URL url = new URL(urlstring);
conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // exception here.
```

But the cast won't compile:

```
06-20 15:58:05.311: E/FNF(30286): java.lang.ClassCastException: libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
```

I found this similar question: [Using java class HttpsURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038026/using-java-class-httpsurlconnection), but I am not importing anything from the sun package.

My imports:

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import android.net.Uri;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import android.util.Log;
import edu.mit.media.funf.storage.RemoteFileArchive;
import edu.mit.media.funf.util.LogUtil;
```

I've been scratching my head about this one for a while now, any suggestions?

Comment: It is a `HttpURLConnection`, you can't cast it to `HttpsURLConnection`. This is the same as the question you linked. You just using another incorrect class

Answer (score 88, accepted):

**Method 1:**
Your `urlString` must begin with `https://` and not `http://` for you to be able to cast it to a `HttpsURLConnection`.

**Method 2:**
if your urlString starts with `http://`, changing `HttpsURLConnection` to `HttpURLConnection` should work

Comment: as a comment, if your urlString starts with http://, changing HttpsURLConnection for HttpURLConnection solved the error :)

Comment: @MatiasElorriaga- your comment is more useful from the answer... thanks.

Comment: I have used java.net.HttpURLConnection for unscured URLs but Google would not accept HttpURLConnection implementation during publish application on play store. Alert message by Play store - "Your app(s) are using an unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier interface. " Please provide any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I had same Exception `java.lang.ClassCastException: libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection`

```
uri = new URL("http://www.google.com");
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) uri.openConnection(); // Exception
```

I changed

```
uri = new URL("http://www.google.com");
```

to

```
uri = new URL("https://www.google.com");
```

Now it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

`url.openConnection();` seems to be returning an object of type `libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl` while you have declared your "conn" object as being of type `import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;`. You need to sort up your imports and used objects. Maybe you missed something in the tutorial you were following.

Answer (score 0):

Simple remove `urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);`

it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

*url.openConnection()* returns HttpURLConnection if your url is an HTTP request, it returns HttpsURLConnection if your url is an HTTPS request.

- you can cast HttpsURLConnection to HttpURLConnection, but the inverse can lead to an exception if your url is an HTTP url, which you have seen.
- so, to use *HttpsURLConnection*, you should always cast your url.openConnection() to *HttpURLConnection*, if you have tasks with *HttpsURLConnection*, example use your own *X509TrustManager*, you should check first if your URL is an HTTPS.

herein a sample code:

```
 HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

 if (url.get_protocol().equals("https")) {
      HttpsURLConnection sconn = (HttpsURLConnection)conn;

      /* do tasks with https connection */
 }
```