# int java.io.InputStream.read(byte[]) on a null object reference in Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection, pdfviewer

I am using a `PDFViewer` library to view documents in an `Activity` which is loaded from a given `url`.

I am using the open source [this library](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) hosted on Git.

Everything works fine in the latest android version `Nougat` & `Oreo`. The file loads up and is shown in the screen just easy.

However, when testing with the older versions like `Marshmallow` & `Kitkat`, the document isn't loaded and I receive the following `error`:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.io.InputStream.read(byte[])' on a null object reference
```

My full Log report is:

```
E/PDFView: load pdf error
           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.io.InputStream.read(byte[])' on a null object reference
               at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.util.Util.toByteArray(Util.java:36)
               at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.source.InputStreamSource.createDocument(InputStreamSource.java:37)
               at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.DecodingAsyncTask.doInBackground(DecodingAsyncTask.java:53)
               at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.DecodingAsyncTask.doInBackground(DecodingAsyncTask.java:25)
               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa2f736e0
D/Link:: http://mylink.com/FileUpload/Master/PDFModule/636586353416035750_सेफ हाउस संचालन सम्बन्धी सूचना.pdf
E/PDFView: load pdf error
           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.io.InputStream.read(byte[])' on a null object reference
               at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.util.Util.toByteArray(Util.java:36)
               at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.source.InputStreamSource.createDocument(InputStreamSource.java:37)
               at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.DecodingAsyncTask.doInBackground(DecodingAsyncTask.java:53)
               at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.DecodingAsyncTask.doInBackground(DecodingAsyncTask.java:25)
               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

My `PDFclass` code is as follows:

```
public void getPdfFile() {
        pdf_link = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("PDF_URL");
        checkStrUrl = pdf_link.substring(pdf_link.lastIndexOf("_") + 1);
        if (!checkFileInDevice(checkStrUrl)) {
            new RetrievePDFStream().execute(pdf_link);
        } else {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Application Documents/" + checkStrUrl);
            pdfView.fromFile(file).load();
        }

    }

    class RetrievePDFStream extends AsyncTask<String, Void, InputStream> {

        @Override
        protected InputStream doInBackground(String... strings) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return null;
            }
            return inputStream;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(InputStream inputStream) {
            pdfView.fromStream(inputStream).load();
        }

    }
```

Comment: It's a simple pdf file document.

Comment: whats the value of `pdf_link`? just use `Log.d` to print it out

Comment: Where exactly do you get the error?

Comment: @pskink I get the following Log detail: D/Link:: http://mylink.com/FileUpload/Master/PDFModule/636586353416035750_सेफ हाउस संचालन सम्बन्धी सूचना.pdf

Comment: @PeterBruins I get `null` value in my `inputStream` when it is returned from `doInBackground()`

Comment: and whats the **full** java stacktrace?

Comment: @pskink edited above

Comment: where are you executing `DecodingAsyncTask`?

Comment: @pskink the `execute()` is present in `getPdfFile()`

Comment: its `RetrievePDFStream`, not `DecodingAsyncTask`

Comment: @pskink where can I find the `DecodingAsyncTask`

Comment: @pskink It is a predefined class which is present in the library itself.

Comment: see the stacktrace, but most likely `RetrievePDFStream#onPostExecute` method is called with null `inputStream` parameter

Comment: @pskink it is returning null only in the older android versions whereas, it is working fine in the newer version.

Comment: so what `IOException` are you getting in `doInBackground`?

Comment: @pskink I tried debugging, but it never steps into the catch block. so the IOException is never printed.

Comment: add `e.printStackTrace()` before returning null

Comment: @pskink still not printing anything

Comment: then add `Log.d` and log the value of `inputStream` and `urlConnection.getResponseCode()` before `return inputStream;`

Comment: @pskink D/InputStream:: null
D/ResponseCode:: 400

Comment: so you have the answer: `400 Bad Request` - it is not `200 OK`

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127578/java-lang-classcastexception-libcore-net-http-httpurlconnectionimpl-cannot-be-c) may help you.

Comment: Even i have similar issue, stuck from days. Don't know how to fix it..