# java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground() Error?

Tags: android

When I click the trial video I added from the admin panel in the emulator, I get such an error.

```
EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
    Process: yupitr.xhub.video, PID: 2749
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
        at yupitr.xhub.video.Methods.Methods.getBitmapFromURL(Methods.java:390)
        at yupitr.xhub.video.Activity.video.All_PlayerActivity$LoadColor.doInBackground(All_PlayerActivity.java:443)
        at yupitr.xhub.video.Activity.video.All_PlayerActivity$LoadColor.doInBackground(All_PlayerActivity.java:430)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

BitmapFromUrl Code Is there a place I should organize here? Where is the problem? I could not find it

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        InputStream input;
        if(Setting.SERVER_URL.contains("https://")) {
            HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            input = connection.getInputStream();
        } else  {
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            input = connection.getInputStream();
        }
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this cast on your code:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
```

and error points to those lines:

```
All_PlayerActivity.java:443
All_PlayerActivity.java:430
```

Comment: check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127578/java-lang-classcastexception-libcore-net-http-httpurlconnectionimpl-cannot-be-c