# Java Login 'Exception Error'- what does it mean?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

Im trying to automate a login using java, and have used this example: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/   to help me do it with another website. The code is below, and so is the output. My question is, what does the error mean, and how do I fix it?

```
public class testing {

  private List<String> cookies;
  private HttpsURLConnection conn;

  private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

String url = "https://www.studentinvestor.org/secure/login.php?dest=http://www.studentinvestor.org/stock-list.php";
String companies = "http://www.studentinvestor.org/stock-list.php";

testing http = new testing();

// make sure cookies is turn on
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());

// 1. Send a "GET" request, so that you can extract the form's data.
String page = http.GetPageContent(url);
String postParams = http.getFormParams(page, "username", ",password");

// 2. Construct above post's content and then send a POST request for
// authentication
http.sendPost(url, postParams);

// 3. success then go to gmail.
String result = http.GetPageContent(companies);
System.out.println(result);
  }

  private void sendPost(String url, String postParams) throws Exception {

URL obj = new URL(url);
conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

// Acts like a browser
conn.setUseCaches(false);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "www.studentinvestor.org");
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept",
    "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6");
for (String cookie : this.cookies) {
    conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
}
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/html");


conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);

// Send post request
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(postParams);
wr.flush();
wr.close();

int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
System.out.println("Post parameters : " + postParams);
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

BufferedReader in = 
         new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();
// System.out.println(response.toString());

  }

  private String GetPageContent(String url) throws Exception {

URL obj = new URL(url);
conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

// default is GET
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

conn.setUseCaches(false);

// act like a browser
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept",
    "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6");
if (cookies != null) {
    for (String cookie : this.cookies) {
        conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
    }
}
int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

BufferedReader in = 
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();

// Get the response cookies
setCookies(conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie"));

return response.toString();

  }

  public String getFormParams(String html, String username, String password)
    throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

System.out.println("Extracting form's data...");

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

// Google form id
Element loginform = doc.getElementById("loginsubmitted");
Elements inputElements = loginform.getElementsByTag("label");
List<String> paramList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Element inputElement : inputElements) {
    String key = inputElement.attr("name");
    String value = inputElement.attr("value");

    if (key.equals("team-name"))
        value = username;
    else if (key.equals("team-password"))
        value = password;
    paramList.add(key + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
    }

// build parameters list
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for (String param : paramList) {
    if (result.length() == 0) {
        result.append(param);
    } else {
        result.append("&" + param);
    }
}
return result.toString();
  }

  public List<String> getCookies() {
    return cookies;
  }

 public void setCookies(List<String> cookies) {
this.cookies = cookies;
  }

}
```

OUTPUT

```
Sending 'GET' request to URL : https://www.studentinvestor.org/secure/login.php?    dest=http://www.studentinvestor.org/stock-list.php
Response Code : 200
Extracting form's data...

Sending 'POST' request to URL : https://www.studentinvestor.org/secure/login.php?   dest=http://www.studentinvestor.org/stock-list.php
Post parameters : 
Response Code : 200
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection cannot be cast to   javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
    at testing.GetPageContent(testing.java:98)
  at testing.main(testing.java:44)
```

Therefore the error message is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection cannot be cast to   javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
        at testing.GetPageContent(testing.java:98)
      at testing.main(testing.java:44)
```

Comment: How much of the code you've copied do you understand? Do you understand what casting is, and what's happening on line 44?

Comment: which line is line 98 of testing?

Comment: Line 44 is  String result = http.GetPageContent(companies);, Line 98 is  conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();. Im afraid I'm a bit of a noob, and therefore do not understand much other than the very basics, so i would appreciate it were you to explain to me what casting is

Comment: A quick search says its turning a variable from one type to another, is this right?

Comment: @BenHarvey casting is when you take an object of one type, and tell the compiler to treat it as a different type

Comment: Okay, so why is there an error in changing its type?

Comment: so the types in question:  `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection`, and `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection`, even thought they have the same name, are in different namespaces, and are probably different types

Comment: Okay, I think i understand. How would i get around this error?

Comment: get rid of the (HttpsURLConnection) part on line 98

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand. How do i not 'do the casting'? Do i have to delete something

Comment: What do I replace it with?

Comment: @BenHarvey you don't replace it with anything per-se.  What you'll probably have to do is one of 2 things.  You'll either have to research the correct way to get an instance of `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection`, or you'll have to rewrite your method to use `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection` instead

Comment: Which one would be the better thing to do?

Comment: How come it worked with gmail but not this website?

Comment: @BenHarvey Do you have any `using` statements, or since this is java, `import`, or something like that at the top of your code?

Comment: import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.CookieHandler;
import java.net.CookieManager;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

Comment: and what do you mean by "it worked with gmail"

Comment: If you see the OP, I got this code from http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/. When I tested it with my gmail account it worked fine. So i went through it with the source code of gmail and the website i want, changing what i needed to change, but got this error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using java class HttpsURLConnection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038026/using-java-class-httpsurlconnection)

Comment: I might have found it. Line 51 I have conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection(); and line 98 i have conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

Comment: Still unsure of what to do though

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me! If you get this error, make sure your URLs are HTTPS, not just http or www!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the exception : sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection cannot be cast to   javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection

Here the protocol of required Url should be Https instead of HTTP.

so using the below code will solve your issue:

String companies = "https://www.studentinvestor.org/stock-list.php";